How can I buy an international flight from Bolivia, considering the cards restrictions for internet purchases?
How can I buy an international flight from Bolivia, considering the cards restrictions for internet purchases?  And airlines offices do not work in the country for now.

Could you link to something about the "cards restrictions for internet purchases"? I cannot find any information on this topic with a cursory search.

most likely scenario is you go to an international airport or the closest office of an airline offering international flights, and buy a ticket in person, possibly paying cash (if indeed your credit card company won't validate transactions made in Bolivia).

You could ask a trusted friend outside Bolivia to purchase the ticket you wish for you, perhaps using using your card, perhaps using theirs.
Note that some airlines, under some circumstances, require that at check-in for the flight the passenger must physically carry and show the credit card used to purchase the ticket. This situation would make a purchase by your overseas friend either difficult or impossible.
